# Composer update not working Invalid version

Tags: php, composer-php

Hi there can anyone please help me with this I can not update the composer I tried deleting composer.lock, I tried composer install, I tried composer update all I am getting is this error:

Loading composer repositories with package information

```
  [UnexpectedValueException]
  Invalid version string ">=7.1.0"


update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--

prefer-lowest] [-i|--interactive] [--root-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

This is my composer.json  file:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "config": {
        "platform": {
            "php": ">=7.1.0"
        },
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^2.3",
         "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.1",
        "brozot/laravel-fcm": "^1.2",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.2",
        "intervention/image": "^2.3",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "laravel/passport": "^3.0",
        "laravel/socialite": "^3.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "~5.0",
        "braintree/braintree_php" : "3.23.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0",
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help what is it that it does not work..

Comment: Show your composer.json file

Comment: Try "`>=7.1`" or "`7.1.*`"

Comment: I have edited my code you can see the composer.json file now @MarcinOrlowski

Comment: what composer version is this? Are you using recent one? If you remove while `platform` node in `config` will it work?

Answer (score 4):

In `platform` config, you have to set the exact version of PHP you want composer to use, not a constraint:

```
    "platform": {
        "php": "7.1.0"
    },
```

https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform